# Remove last string value in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a  loop in php

```
foreach($Array as $key =>$value) 
 {
     $TotalLine .=  " Qualification =".$value." OR ";
 }
  echo $TotalLine;
```

Prints

```
  Qualification =1 OR Qualification =2 OR Qualification =3 OR Qualification =4 OR
```

Now i need to remove last **OR** in that line, Desired Output must look like

```
 Qualification =1 OR Qualification =2 OR Qualification =3 OR Qualification =4
```

How to do this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115530/5447994), you can also take a look at [this article](http://vijayasankar.me.pn/blog/2017/09/08/php-implode-or-trim-concatenating-strings-in-a-loop/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use php `rtrim()` function for this

```
foreach($Array as $key =>$value) 
{
    $TotalLine .=  " Qualification =".$value." OR ";
}
echo rtrim($TotalLine,"OR");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/857861)**

```
$TotalLine = [];
foreach ($Array as $key => $value) {
    $TotalLine[] = " Qualification =" . $value;
}
echo implode(" OR ", $TotalLine);
```

---

Or, if you don't want this method, you can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim):

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/857860)**

```
rtrim($TotalLine," OR");
```

Here, it is not needed to use the last space like `" OR "` since trim considers every character as a mask. Read the doc

---

But former one is most preferable and neat. You use arrays and then join the values using `implode` function. The latter one trims out the last specified string.

**Be aware:** When you use `trim` the characters in the mask will be removed. Here when your value is just numeric there will be no problem. But when you have string like `ROAR` your last `R` gets trimmed out as well. [Demo](https://eval.in/857916) for it too. Just for your knowledge! Or, [*this article*](http://vijayasankar.me.pn/blog/2017/09/08/php-implode-or-trim-concatenating-strings-in-a-loop/) that evolved out of this question.

Comment: *But former one is most preferable and neat* - By who? You? I definitely think the second one is better for a simple reason that if a newbie looks at the code it would be easier to figure what a function named `trim` is doing than `implode`.

Comment: I strongly prefer the first option. If I was a newbie looking at the `rtrim` version, I'd wonder why you were building a string only to then remove some of it. This is one of those questions that's [trying to fix the wrong problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - the question shouldn't be "how to I remove the last part of a string", it should be "how do I build a string with a common separator". If it was worded like that, no one would be talking about `rtrim`.

Comment: And understanding that the argument for `rtrim()` is a series of characters, and not an exact matching string is important... two spaces in this case is meaningless, and if the last characters of the last `$value` include `O` or `R` it will give unexpected results

Comment: @MarkBaker That is the reason why I have specified `rtrim($TotalLine," OR"); ` and not `rtrim($TotalLine," OR "); `. Also I updated with the notice as well for this case: https://eval.in/857916

Comment: Oh, my edit and your comment came simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `end()` function like this :

```
foreach($Array as $key =>$value){    
  $TotalLine .=  " Qualification =".$value;
  if(!end($value)){
    $TotalLine .= " OR ";
  }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative soulution without foreach loop.**

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$string = implode(" OR Qualification =", $array);
echo "Qualification =$string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `!empty()`

**PHP :**

```
<?php
$Array =[1,2,3,4];
$TotalLine="";
foreach($Array as $key =>$value) 
{
    !empty($TotalLine) ? $TotalLine .=  " OR Qualification =".$value : $TotalLine =  "Qualification =".$value;

}
echo $TotalLine;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Qualification =1 OR Qualification =2 OR Qualification =3 OR Qualification =4
```